# Complex normed spaces and functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

Let $h : V \rightarrow C$ be a linear functional,where $V$ is a complex normed space. Prove that $h$ is continuous iff  $\exists S^{open} \subsetneq V$  so that $h(S) \neq C$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I would appreciate any hints or help with how to proceed..

Comment: HINT. If  $h$ is discontinuous and $U$ is a bounded open nbhd of $0$ in the space $V,$ there is a sequence  $(u_n)_n$  of members of $U$ that converges to $0$ with $(|h(u_n)|)_n$ diverging to $\infty$ because $\sup \{|h(v)|/\|v\|: 0\ne v\in V\}=\infty.$.... So for $z\in \Bbb C,$ if $n$ is large enough   that $w=v_n (z/h(v_n)\in U$   then $z=f(w)\in f(U).$